# Compile inside test don't create the required result

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I'm using karma for unit test my angular directive. I've removed parts from my directive until I removed it all, but I'm obviously missing something.
this is the test:

```
element = angular.element('<div ng-repeat="option in options">ASD</div>');
element = $compile(element)(scope);
expect(element.text()).toMatch('ASD');
```

why does the compile don't run ng-repeat?

Edit:
this is the beforeEach:

```
var element;
var scope;
   beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.options = [{}];
    }));
```

Comment: Are you defining an array named options on the scope, so it can repeat over it?

Comment: yes. I'm injecting $rootScope ->
scope = $rootScope.$new() ->
scope.options = [{}];

Comment: Add `scope.$digest();` at the end of your beforeEach ;)

Comment: doesn't work, try adding scope.$digest also after compile and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in beforeEach:

```
 scope.$apply(function() {
    . . . set up your scope here
    element = $compile('<div ng-repeat="option in options">ASD</div>')(scope);
 }
```

now in each 'it' section you should be able to see your element compiled.

The key here is :

1. Don't compile `angular.element(<html>)`, but compile `<html>` directly
2. Wrap it in `scope.$apply` (it would probably work without wrapping and
   just calling it afterwards, but this is more proper way).